# German ä ü ö umlauts query isnt working

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to save something into a database with a normaly mysql-query via php.

Its working pretty good, but when it comes to umlauts/mutations its not working.

I tried it with regular expressions, but this didnt work either.

Any ideas?

Thx Nubu

Comment: read this : http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: Do you ahve any kind of error? Also you need to make your columns in table with UTF-8

Comment: This is not a good question. What is working? What is not? What is the expected behavior? What is your code supposed to do? Can we see it?

Comment: http://kunststube.net/frontback

Comment: Sorry kunststube, i just wanted to add a new person into my database, with all kinds of information (firstname, lastname etc.) and also i wanted to make it happen that letters like ä, ü, ö can be inserted into the database ... what is actually not possible thats what i wanted.